# Save values from POST request of a list of dicts

Tags: python, flask, quart

I a trying to expose an API (if that's the correct way to say it). I am using Quart, a python library made out of Flask and this is what my code looks like:

```
async def capture_post_request(request_json):
    for item in request_json:
        callbackidd = item['callbackid']
        print(callbackidd)

@app.route('/start_work/', methods=['POST'])
async def start_work():
    content_type = request.headers.get('content-type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        request_json = await request.get_json()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(capture_post_request(request_json)) 
        body = "Async Job Started"
        return body
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'
```

My schema looks like that:

```py
[
    {
        "callbackid": "dd",
        "itemid": "234r",
        "input": [
            {
                "type": "thistype",
                "uri": "www.uri.com"
            }
        ],
        "destination": {
            "type": "thattype",
            "uri": "www.urino2.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "statusCode": "202"
    }
]
```

So far what I am getting is this error:

```
line 11, in capture_post_request
    callbackidd = item['callbackid']
KeyError: 'callbackid'
```

I've tried so many stackoverflow posts to see how to iterate through my list of dicts but nothing worked. At one point in my `start_work` function I was using the `get_data(as_text=True)` method but still no results. In fact with the last method (or attr) I got:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any help on how to access those values is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Quart has a background task feature, see [docs](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/how_to_guides/background_tasks.html) which I'd recommend you use rather than the loop.create_task call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema indicates there are **two** items in the `request_json`. The first indeed has the `callbackid`, the 2nd only has `statusCode`.

Debugging this should be easy:

```py
async def capture_post_request(request_json):
    for item in request_json:
        print(item)
        callbackidd = item.get('callbackid')
        print(callbackidd) # will be None in case of the 2nd 'item'
```

This will print two dicts:

```py
{
    "callbackid": "dd",
    "itemid": "234r",
    "input": [
        {
            "type": "thistype",
            "uri": "www.uri.com"
        }
    ],
    "destination": {
        "type": "thattype",
        "uri": "www.urino2.com"
    }
}
```

And the 2nd, the cause of your KeyError:

```py
{
    "statusCode": "202"
}
```

I included the 'fix' of sorts already:

```py
callbackidd = item.get('callbackid')
```

This will default to `None` if the key isn't in the dict.

Hopefully this will get you further!

**Edit**

How to work with only the dict containing your key? There are two options.

First, using `filter`. Something like this:

```py
def has_callbackid(dict_to_test):
    return 'callbackid' in dict_to_test

list_with_only_list_callbackid_items = list(filter(has_callbackid, request_json))
# Still a list at this point! With dicts which have the `callbackid` key
```

Filter accepts some arguments:

1. Function to call to determine if the value being tested should be filtered out or not.
2. The iterable you want to filter

Could also use a 'lambda function', but it's a bit evil. But serves the purpose just as well:

```py
list_with_only_list_callbackid_items = list(filter(lambda x: 'callbackid' in x, request_json))
# Still a list at this point! With dict(s) which have the `callbackid` key
```

Option 2, simply loop over the result and only grab the one you want to use.

```py
found_item = None # default
for item in request_json:
    if 'callbackid' in item:
        found_item = item
        break # found what we're looking for, stop now
# Do stuff with the found_item from this point.
```

Comment: it was so simple and yet it helped! thanks! any idea how to specify that I want the for loop to search only on the first dictionary?

Comment: I'll edit my post with some examples for that

Comment: See edit, hope that helps!